# Error & Threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm building a small Java app to calculate monthly expenses for a department:

- Employee: abstract superclass, contains getExpenses();
- Developer: subclass, implements getExpenses(), returns 1000
- QATester: subclass, implements getExpenses(), returns 500
- Manager: shown
- MainClass: shown

Currently working on MainClass.  I have 2 question/areas I'd like some input. 1)  getting these errors from these lines.

```
Manager managerA = new Manager(tester1, dev1);
Manager managerB = new Manager(managerA);
```

Multiple markers at this line
- The constructor Manager(QATester, Developer) is undefined
- Manager cannot be resolved to a type

2) I'm new to threading and was considering running this app on a thread, maybe adding a UI, suggestions/examples?

Thanks.

```
package main;

import expenseApp.Developer;
import expenseApp.Manager;
import expenseApp.QATester;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        QATester tester1 = new QATester();
        Developer dev1 = new Developer();
        Manager managerA = new Manager(tester1, dev1);
        Manager managerB = new Manager(managerA);
    }
}

package expenseApp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Manager extends Employee
{
    private ArrayList<Manager> managerList;
    private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList;

    public void add(Employee employee) 
    {
        if(employee instanceof Manager) 
        {
            managerList.add((Manager) employee);
        }
        else 
        {
            employeeList.add(employee);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getExpenses() 
    {
         return 300;
    }

    public int getTotalExpenses() 
    {
        int totalExpenses = 0;

        for(Manager manager : managerList)
        {
            totalExpenses += manager.getTotalExpenses();
        }

        for(Employee employee : employeeList)
        {
            totalExpenses += employee.getExpenses();
        }

        return totalExpenses;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a constructor for a `Manager` that has that signature?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with threading. Also, what is your question?

Comment: ...that might be the ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: Your calling code can't find the `Manager` class for some reason. While it's strange because the error occurs on the constructor line instead of the `import` line (which is usually the case), I'd suggest fixing you constructors first (see my next section) before looking into that `cannot be resolved into a type` error, as it might be a subsequent fault.

Furthermore, your `Manager` class does not have any constructor defined, which implicitly defines the default (empty) constructor:

```
public Manager() {
}
```

You need to provide all the constructors you need. From your code I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
public Manager(List<Manager> managers, List<Employee> employees) {
    this.managers = new ArrayList<>(managers);
    this.employees = new ArrayList<>(employees);
}
```

**Question 2**: "Running on a thread" - your application is already running on a thread, the `main` thread. What do you want to do that makes you think you need threading? While adding a UI might be a valid response, there is the possibility of building a UI without explicit threading on your side. My suggestion would be to keep it as simple as necessary, from what I see, you don't *need* multithreading right now, and I'd not introduce a whole lot of [synchronization issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)) unless it's necessary.